# Prolog hide returned predicate value

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

Lets say i have simple hello world code

```
hworld:-writeln('hello world').
```

This code always returns something like this:

```
hello world
true.
```

As far as i understand prolog, it returns either variable value (of X i.e. fact(5,X).) or true/false, if predicate can be solved (i.e. fact(5,120).). 
What i need is to hide true/false predicate result on stdout (so there will be only results of writeln() predicate). How to do so? Thanks.

Comment: You are using a toplevel loop for Prolog. And that loop gives such answers. If you want to omit these answers you must call your Prolog entirely differently - see the manual, but it is not recommended for beginners to start without the toplevel

Comment: Why do you *need* to hide the true/false result?

Comment: Its for a school project, where we were instructed to omit these messages. I found out a bit dirty solution, i did it like this:
`hworld:-writeln('hello world'),halt.`

Comment: That is a bit dirty, but not sure what else one would do with a ridiculous requirement.